# Memory Leak while using CvSeq in cvFindContours

Tags: opencv

I am new to OpenCV and i faced some problem while using it.

Currently i am work on Binary Partitioning Tree (BPT) algorithm. Basically I need split the image into many regions, and based on some parameter. 2 regions will merged and form 1 new region, which consists of these 2 regions.

I managed to get initial regions by using cvWatershed. I also created a vector to store these regions, each in 1 vector block. However, I get memory leak when I tried to move the contour information into vector. It says, memory leak.

```
for (int h = 0; h <compCount; h++)  // compCount - Amount of regions found through cvWaterShed
{
    cvZero(WSRegion);               // clears out an image, used for painting 
    Region.push_back(EmptyNode);    // create an empty vector slot
    CvScalar RegionColor = colorTab[h]; // the color of the region in watershed

    for (int i = 0; i <WSOut->height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <WSOut->width; j++)
        {
            CvScalar s = cvGet2D(WSOut, i, j);  // get pixel color in watershed image
            if (s.val[0] == RegionColor.val[0] && s.val[1] == RegionColor.val[1] && s.val[2] == RegionColor.val[2])
            {
                cvSet2D(WSRegion, i, j, cvScalarAll(255));  // paint the pixel to white if it has the same color with the region[h]

            }
        }
    }

    MemStorage = cvCreateMemStorage();   // create memory storage
    cvFindContours(WSRegion, MemStorage, &contours, sizeof(CvContour), CV_RETR_LIST);
    Region[h].RegionContour = cvCloneSeq(contours);  // clone and store in vector Region[h]
    Region[h].RegionContour->h_next = NULL;
}
```

Is it any ways I can solve this problem? Or is there any alternative that I do not need to create a new memory storage for every region vector？ Thank You in advance

Answer (score 2):

You should create the memory storage only once before the loop, cvFindContours can use that, and after the loop you should release the storage with:

```
void cvReleaseMemStorage(CvMemStorage** storage)
```

You can also take a look here for the CvMemStorage specification :
http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/dynamic_structures.html?highlight=cvreleasememstorage#CvMemStorage

EDIT:

Your next problem is with `cvCloneSeq()`. Here are some specifications for it:

```
CvSeq* cvCloneSeq(const CvSeq* seq, CvMemStorage* storage=NULL )
Parameters: 

seq – Sequence
storage – The destination storage block to hold the new sequence header and the copied data, if any. If it is NULL, the function uses the storage block containing the input sequence.
```

As you can see if you don't specify a different memory storage, it will clone the sequence in the same memory block as the input. When you are releasing the memory storage after the loop you are also releasing the last contour and it's clone that you pushed in the list.

Comment: I moved the create memory storage statement outside of the for loop. 
It works, but when i release the memory storage, the last vector block's RegionContour had been released too. Any suggestions to avoid this?

Comment: Edited response for your new problem. Hope it helps.